# How to add rounded border for PopupMenu in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, rounded-corners, popupmenu

Is there any way I could create custom pop up with rounded borders?
This is my current code and design:

```
                child: Container(
                 child: PopupMenuButton(
                   onSelected: _savedLocationOptionSelected,
                   itemBuilder: (context) {
                     return SavedLocationOptions.choises.map((value) {
                       return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                         value: value,
                         child: Text(value),
                       );
                     }).toList();
                   },
                   icon: Icon(
                     Icons.more_vert,
                     color: Colors.grey[300],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue here... the shape property is missing ^^

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You just add like this at PopupMenuButton

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
               Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
),
```

Example

```
   PopupMenuButton(
      child: Text("Show Popup Menu"),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context) => [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("pub.dev"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Flutter"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Google.com"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("https://blogdeveloperspot.blogspot.com/search?q=flutter"),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer given by @Taz
You can use themes to have settings for rounded corners in each and every Popups at one place:

```
MaterialApp(
  // ....
  theme: ThemeData(
  // ....
  popupMenuTheme: PopupMenuThemeData(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way is:

```
shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
       ),
```

Answer (score -2):

Click Right on "PopupMenuButton" in your code then Paste it in The Page will Opend Named By "PopupMenu" and Paste the Code in This Link to Dart File

Then Visit this Link : 
[image]https://github.com/mohamedashraf8850/flutter/edit/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart